# What's the purpose of glVertexPointer?

Tags: opengl, glsl, nvidia

I was looking at the **Particles** examples of CUDA and I couldn't find where to they make the link between the array of vertices and the variables in the shader. From what I've read and actually the way I've been doing it is

```
...
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData( ... )
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer( ... );
...
```

however what I found in Nvidia's example looks like

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, m_vbo);
glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

if (m_colorVBO)
{
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, m_colorVBO);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, m_numParticles);

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

which I believe is something similar to what I do. So my questions are

1. What's the difference between those two ways of passing data to the shader?
2. Should I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first way is the modern, generic way of sending attributes. The second one is older, where vertices, normals, colors etc. had their own hard-coded attributes. It should not be used in modern code.

Answer (score 5):

`glVertexAttribPointer` is the current and preferred way of passing attributes to the GPU.

`glVertexPointer` is part of the old and deprecated fixed function pipeline and set openGL to use the VBO for the attribute.

in essence what is defined with glVertexPointer is what would be passed if you looped over the buffer and called `glVertex4f(x,y,z,w)` for the values.

Comment: Actually, it is not related to `glBegin/glEnd`at all. Those are just the builtin attributes for the fixed-function pipeline. The distinction between immediate mode and vertex arrays is not really relevant here. Note that there is also the `glVertexAttrib*` family of functions, which allows one to use generic attributes in immediate mode with `Begin/End` in legacy GL / compatibility profile.